# ascii to hexadecimal in js

Tags: javascript, string, hex, substring

I'm trying to convert a .onion's url (the public key information or whatever) into a logo similar to the AACS flag that people used. I think it's a creative way to share deepweb links while allowing you to authenticate the link's address.

However, life sucks when code doesn't work.

Here's the live fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/whitingcameronlinux/th0jrx8h/4/

What I need is a conversion that preserves characters in js even as they're converted to hex. I WANT THE CHARACTERS (and that parseInt toString trick doesn't help much)...

```
$("#click").click(function () {
        // Grab url (k03rjptlbsi7dq3y.onion)
        //var url = window.location.host;
        // hopefully the same kind of data
        var url = 'ko3rjptlbsi7dq3y.onion';

        // remove .onion
        var onlyurl = url.substr(0, 16);

        // turn into hex
        var hexresult = parseInt(onlyurl).toString();

        // grab hex colors
        var bar0 = "#" + hexresult.substring(0, 6);
        var bar1 = "#" + hexresult.substring(5, 6);
        var bar2 = "#" + hexresult.substring(11, 6);
        var bar3 = "#" + hexresult.substring(17, 6);
        var bar4 = "#" + hexresult.substring(23, 6);

        // remainder goes here
        var plus = "+" + hexresult.substring(29, 2);

        //new elements:
        $("#validate").append("<style id=\"validate\"> #bar0{background-color:" + $bar0 + "}#ba

r1{background-color:" + $bar1 + "}#bar2{background-color:" + $bar2 + "}#bar3{background-color:" + $bar3 + "}#bar4{background-color:" + $bar4 + "}</style>");
            $("#bar4").html($plus);
});
```

How can I convert them to get the correct amount of information?

(I know they're not compatible with hex to begin with, that's why I have to convert the ascii to hex in the first place)

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple and elegant way:

```
function ascii2hex(str){
  var u=unescape(encodeURIComponent(str))
  return u.split('').map(function(c){return c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)}).join('')
}
```